# Ветвление в Pascal ABC

Tags: pascalabc.net, условия

Новичок в программировании. Не корректно получается ветвление. Суть проблемы:
Пишу программу-симулятор работы электрической цепи. Рисую пока все примитивом (линия, прямоугольник, круг и пр.)
Работая в графическом редакторе нужно, чтобы по нажатию мышки в определенном месте перечерчивал ранее нарисованный рисунок (как и что перечертить я забиваю руками). Использую вот такую конструкцию:

````
BEGIN
{1ШУ} SetPenColor(ClRed); SetPenWidth(5); line(388,25,413,25); TextOut(376,7,'1ШУ(ЕС1)'); SetPenWidth(1); line(400,25,400,50);
      
{Автомат ШУ} SetPenColor(clBlack); line(400,65,400,340); line(400,65,390,50); TextOut(407,50,'SF'); Rectangle(407,66,414,73);

{Шинки}  SetPenWidth(5); line(388,370,413,370); TextOut(389,351,'EC3'); SetPenWidth(1); line(400,370,400,385); 
 
{Цепь 61} line(400,385,480,385); line(480,385,495,375); TextOut(458,368,'SF1'); line(495,385,570,385); Rectangle(500,375,507,382);

{ДЕЙСТВИЯ}
{Заводка пружины привода}

  {Включение автомата SF1}
      OnMousedown := (x, y, mb) ->  
       if (x > 500) and (x < 507) and (y > 375) and (y < 382) and (mb = 1) then   begin
      {Шинки} SetPenColor(clwhite); Rectangle(480,385,495,375); SetPenColor(clred); line(480,385,495,385); line(400,385,480,385); line(495,385,570,385);
       SetPenWidth(5); line(388,370,413,370);   SetPenWidth(1); line(400,370,400,385); 
        end;
 
    OnMouseup := (x, y, mb) ->  
      if  (x > 500) and (x < 507) and (y > 375) and (y < 382) and (mb = 1) then   begin
      SetPenColor(clwhite); Rectangle(480,387,495,375); SetPenColor(clblack); line(480,385,495,375);
      SetPenColor(clblack); SetPenWidth(5); line(388,370,413,370);   SetPenWidth(1); line(400,370,400,385); line(400,385,480,385); line(495,385,570,385); 
        end;
 
  {Включение автомата SF}
    OnMousedown := (x, y, mb) ->  
      if  (x > 407) and (x < 414) and (y > 66) and (y < 73) and (mb = 1) then   begin
      setpencolor(clWhite); Rectangle(390,50,402,65); Rectangle(1190,50,1202,65); setpencolor(clred); Line(400,50,400,340); Line(1200,50,1200,320);
      Line(400,25,400,50); Line(1200,25,1200,50);
     end;
   
    OnMouseup := (x, y, mb) ->  
      if  (x > 407) and (x < 414) and (y > 66) and (y < 73) and (mb = 1) then   begin
      setpencolor(clWhite); Rectangle(390,50,402,65); Rectangle(1190,50,1202,65); 
      {Н.О. SF} setpencolor(clblack);  Line(390,50,400,65); Line(1190,50,1200,65);
      {черные линии до низа} Line(400,65,400,340); Line(1200,65,1200,320);

end;
END.```


При нажатии на прямоугольник радом с SF, SF1 должна происходить анимация (по отдельности должна перекрашиваться и перерисовываться цепь). Сейчас работает только  анимация при нажатии на прямоугольник рядом с SF. 2 первых условия программой напрочь игнорируются.

Вопрос такой: не могу разобраться куда вставлять end-ы. Если я ставлю все 4 штуки в самом конце, то все идет последовательно (т.е. последние условия не выполняются, пока не выполнятся первые два).Если ставлю после каждого оператора, то не выполняются первые 2 условия.
Как сделать правильно так, чтобы программа выполняла любое из условий независимо друг от друга?
````

Comment: Как новичок в программировании, выслушайте совет от бывшего новичка. Ваш очень свежий и индивидуальный подход к форматированию программы допустим ровно до того момента, когда другим, скучным, старым и не стильным программистам придется ломать об него глаза. Вот как сейчас.

Answer (score 1):

В данном коде происходит **не выполнение действий**, а **назначение обработчиков событий**.

Так вот обработчики  `OnMousedown` и  `OnMouseUp` переназначаются, и код первых версий никогда не выполняется при возникновении событий мыши.

If-условия для каждой области должны быть внутри одного обработчика.

```
 OnMousedown := (x, y, mb) ->  
    if (x > 500) and (x < 507) and (y > 375) and (y < 382) and (mb = 1) then   begin
   {Шинки} SetPenColor(clwhite); Rectangle(480,385,495,375); SetPenColor(clred); line(480,385,495,385); line(400,385,480,385); line(495,385,570,385);
    SetPenWidth(5); line(388,370,413,370);   SetPenWidth(1); line(400,370,400,385); 
     end 
else if (x > 407) and (x < 414) and (y > 66) and (y < 73) and (mb = 1) then 
 begin
   setpencolor(clWhite); Rectangle(390,50,402,65); Rectangle(1190,50,1202,65); setpencolor(clred); Line(400,50,400,340); Line(1200,50,1200,320);
   Line(400,25,400,50); Line(1200,25,1200,50);
  end;
```

и аналогично для Up

Замечу, что такими громоздкими лямбда-функции делать не стоит, тут лучше обычные. И условия будут компактнее  с функцией `PtInRect`. Кроме того, использовано море магических чисел. Вероятно, их лучше задать константами, которые даже могут быть сведены в массив.

---

Лямбда-функции для обработчиков `OnMouseXX` независимы, каждая представляет законченный кодовый блок, поэтому `end` относится только к `begin`-у после условия `if`  в своей функции

```
OnMousedown := (x, y, mb) ->  
       if (x > х1) and (x < х2) and (y > у1) and (y < у1) and (mb = 1) then 
       begin
                        {Нажимаю ЛКМ в прямоугольнике №1 с координатами х1,х2,у1,у1}
          ...
       end;
```

Comment: правил основное сообщение. Добавил только часть, где можно на примере все понять